# How to handle backslash "\" escape characters in q string and heredocument

Tags: ruby

Ruby Newbie here.  I do not understand why Ruby looks inside `%q` and escapes the `\`.

I am using Ruby to generate Latex code. I need to generate `\\\hline` which is used in Latex for table making. I found `\\\hline` as input generated `\hline` even though the string was inside `%q`.

Here is MWE

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w
tmp = File.open('foo.txt','w')
str = %q[\\\hline]
tmp.write(str)
tmp.close
```

The file `foo.txt` has this

```
 \\hline
```

Ruby does give the warning

```
   warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
```

But this should not be generated since this is supposed to be escaped strings?

Now I tried it with Python multiline raw strings (similar to Ruby's `%q`)

```
file = open('foo4.txt', 'w')
str = r"""\\\hline"""
file.write(str)
file.close()
```

And the file again contains `\\\hline` as expected.

Am I doing something wrong in Ruby?

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: The file foo2.txt contains `      \\\hline` when I run the snippet ẅith the HEREDOC `str = <<'EOT'`, that is 6 spaces followed by 3 backslashes and the word hline.

Comment: @steenslag You are correct, sorry about that, I must have mixed it with another file from some other test. Will remove this part from the question. But the HEREDOC solution is not suitable for what I want. I prefer to have used `%q` since I need to be able to build larger strings by appending smaller ones, and using HEREDOC makes this very hard due to indentations.   Python `r"""` actually works best for what I want so far as it handles all back slashes, and allows me to append or insert strings in the middle without any special indentations needed as the case when using HEREDOC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = <<'TEXT'
hello %s
\\\hline
%s
TEXT

name = "Graig"
msg = "Goodbye"
puts str % [name, msg]
```

The heredoc does not have escape chars when it's delimiter is in single quotes. It does have a form of interpolation. The code above has this output:

```
hello Graig
\\\hline
Goodbye
```

More fancy is using a hash for interpolation:

```
str = <<'TEXT'
hello %{name}
\\\hline
%{msg}, %{name}
TEXT

puts str % {name: "Graig", msg: "Goodbye"}
```

Output:

```
hello Graig
\\\hline
Goodbye, Graig
```

Comment: wow! thanks, that is what I wanted exactly. I have been trying to figure how to do this, and I did not know that there is this trick of using `%s` like this. I am sure Sergio would not mind if I accept your answer instead, as it does what I want. thanks again. I'll stick now with Ruby for a while :)

Comment: Well, your solution is good, but it does not work for all cases I have :(, my strings have `%` in them. Here is example: 
`str = <<'TEXT'
hello %{name}
<style>
            video {
              width: 100%    !important;
            }
</style>
TEXT

puts str % {name : "Graig"}
`
Can you see a way around this? The `%` in the raw text is confusing the other `%`. I like the hash solution, but if there is a way not to have if be mixed up with any other `%` in the string. I have lots of CSS  and HTML in there also, which uses `%` in some places.

Comment: I can't even escape the "%" in the "100%" string. I tried "100\%" but it still does not work.

Comment: Ehm... this is getting hacky but you could replace the % by something like %{p} in the heredoc, and add `p: "%"` to the hash.

Answer (score 1):

`%q` and `%Q` are alternatives to single-quoted and double-quoted strings, respectively. They're typically used when a string contains quotes themselves (HTML is a typical example), so it's to avoid noisy quote escaping.

Single-quoted strings offer no string interpolation and no escaping. Except for two exceptions: the single quote and the backslash itself. In a `%q` string you don't need to escape the quote, but need to escape the backslash.

```
puts %q[\\\\\\hline 'some words']

# >> \\\hline 'some words'
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes

Comment: Thanks. So this means %q and %Q are not useful for me. So my only other option is to use EOT? But then this also does not scape the '\' as you can see?  I do not want to manually escape '\' ofcourse each time. I am looking for similar behaviour as with Perl or Python.

Comment: I'm afraid that all string types in ruby escape backslashes. What you could do is to store your content in plain text files. This way you get to not duplicate backslashes and ruby will handle the escaping upon loading the file. Or you can just use Perl :trollface:

Comment: OK, thanks for confirmation. This is not good news for me. Only reason I am trying Ruby is for generating Latex, which has lots of `\\\` stuff in it. I am surprised by this. Ok, will go back to Perl for now (until I find something better ;)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The Ruby Programming Language p. 52, about heredocs: "If you want to be very, very literal, allowing no escape character whatsoever, place your delimiter in single quotes. "  OP's heredoc example actually works for me